# Why didn't the Order of the Phoenix destroy the prophecy?

Tags: harry-potter, prophecy

Why didn't the Order of the Phoenix destroy the prophecy?

After all:

1. Dumbledore had already heard and memorised the prophecy.
2. Though prophecies cannot be taken off the shelf by anyone other than the subjects of the prophecy, they can certainly be destroyed (Harry and co. did).
3. It would have been safer. If the prophecy was destroyed, the Order would not have to literally sit in front of the door to the Department of Mysteries to protect it.
4. I think it would be helpful because Voldemort still thinks it is important (even though we know it isn't) and if it was destroyed, he would know that the only way to hear it would be to get the memory from Dumbledore (the only wizard he ever feared).

I have never heard any convincing argument against this alternative and therefore am convinced that it is a plot hole, but would like to hear what you all think.

Comment: Because they didn't have access to it? Even in most muggle government facilities even an employee can't just wander around anywhere they like, much less go break stuff.

Comment: 6 underage wizards/witches and several death eaters got in undetected. At least 6 of them through the visitor's entrance.

Comment: At great (perceived) need.  It doesn't seem like the Order to break into the ministry to destroy something.

Comment: But it's not just to destroy *something*, but rather to destroy a rather important object that would save the lives of others and throw Voldemort off - as I mentioned in the comments of @DVK's answer. Why would the Order bother sitting in front of the door to protect it, rather than get rid of it altogether.

Comment: This has been addressed in fanfiction. I can't remember the story, but there was one where Harry records a fake prophecy taunting Voldemort and replaces the real one with it. The real one was then destroyed. Yes, I know I shouldn't have put this as an answer, but as a comment. I wasn't clear on that point when I posted it. I am now.

Comment: @Kevin that was the Dumbledore's Army.

Comment: There's no actual way to destroy the prophecy. The ones in the Department of Mysteries were just records of prophecies. It's not possible to destroy an intangible thing!

Answer (score 15):

Because there was no point in destroying it.

Voldemort was seeking the prophecy because he thought it would help him to destroy Harry Potter.

In reality, the information in the prophecy was NOT in any way helpful to him, even if he had heard it; which is why Dumbledore didn't bother.

> “The one with the power to vanquish the - Dark Lord approaches… born to those who have thrice defied him, born as the seventh month dies… and the Dark Lord will mark him as his equal, but he will have power the Dark Lord knows not… and either must die at the hand of the other for neither can live while the other survives… the one with the power to vanquish the Dark Lord will be born as the seventh month dies…”

Not exactly a recipe for getting rid of Potter.

As a matter of fact, Dumbledore probably **wanted** DEs to waste time trying to get the Prophecy - if he didn't he would not have bothered posting guards in the Ministry. Destroying the prophecy would have prevented such a tactics from being useable.

Comment: In addition, from the other side of things, it's a common trope that attempting to circumvent a prophecy never ends well... And destroying one is a way to try to circumvent it; keeping someone who is 'meant' to hear it from hearing it.  And, of course, if you destroy one, then you suddenly discover that you needed clarification on one word that would 'change everything', now that you can't get it.  The Ministry of Magic is at least a LITTLE genre-savvy, it looks like :)

Comment: @KHW I don't think it would be circumventing because Voldemort had already done the damage.

Comment: @DVK I agree that the prophecy meant nothing, it was not helpful, and would not help him even if he did get it. That being said, the Order risked their lives trying to protect it. By destroying it, I think it would have been  more of a curveball to let Voldemort wrestle with trying to get the prophecy out of the only person who heard the full version - who is the only one he ever feared. This way, Voldemort would have wasted a lot more time on trying to figure out that the prophecy meant nothing. Also, it would have put none of the Order's lives in danger... except Dumbledore.

Comment: @Anduril_1251 - Quite true; I'm talking about generically.  You don't try to change a prophecy because 'it never works well'; same idea -- trying to destroy it means it will just smack you in some other way.  Knowing that, they restrict it to the people involved being able to hear it; fairly genre-savvy in that it doesn't attempt to prevent it, but helps avoid collateral damage from other people trying to get in on it or respond to it.

Comment: @KHW I see now you meant generically, but I'm still not convinced of the generic case; imagine a scenario: A character makes a prophecy, no one hears it, and the prophecy is destroyed. The destruction of a prophecy in this case seems to not matter much or to produce any collateral damage.

Comment: Why is this information not helpful to Voldemort?"the Dark Lord will mark him as his equal, but he will have power the Dark Lord knows not" is something which would have made him more careful in choosing Harry. And if he was clever enough, "either must die at the hand of the other for neither can live while the other survives" woold have warned him against taking Harry's blood and duelling him. Even at the time of OotP, he would have figured out that killing Harry may somehow not work.

Comment: And Dumbledore posting guards at the Ministry wanting to waste the time of DE's seems to be really bad inference.

Comment: @NUnnikrishnan - Voldemort ALREADY marked Harry as equal and ALREADY took Harry's blood by the time of events in OotP.

Comment: Even at the time of OotP, he would have figured out that killing Harry may somehow not work. As Dumbledore says, "thinking to strengthen himself, he took a part of your mother’s sacrifice into himself. If he could only have understood the precise and terrible power of that sacrifice, he would not, perhaps, had dared to touch your blood. . . . But then, if he had been able to understand, he could not be Lord Voldemort, and might never have murdered at all." Hearing "neither can live while the other survives" might lead him to a flash of insight, who knows?

Comment: If he chose to get a new body without Harry's blood then, he could still kill Harry but Harry would not be able return from "King's Cross". Dumbledore knew better to avoid that distant possibility is the reason I suppose he cared for the Prophecy record.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe prophecies can't be destroyed until they're heard.  Maybe after all the prophecies fell and broke, the shelves reset themselves and the prophecies came back together just like before.  Kind of like the time when Dumbledore flicked his wand and everything in the house appeared as it was before; broken mirrors repaired themselves, the walls, curtains, chandelier, etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).